# Getting Json array and inserting into mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

So I am getting using this api and I want to put it into my mongo database:

http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable

is there an easy way to just get the standing array and insert it into the database, or do I have to parse the json and do a load of appends to the document at insert?

Comment: Which language will you use to access Mongodb?

Comment: sorry, missed that. Java.

Comment: https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html . You basically of course need to parse the JSON, but that could well be your simplest way to result in BSON documents for insertion. Unless I'm missing something, my eyes are telling me that's just one document "containing" an array. If you don't want the direct translation, then it's not really clear what you want to do.